# Why are extremely small masses expected to be in relativistic motion?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, momentum, mass, estimation

For example, neutrinos have an extremely small mass and are expected to be in relativistic motion. Why is that so?

Comment: if they have  a mass, whatever small it is - they cannot reach the speed of light, however, if it is really small, even for relatively small energies E, E can be  of order of mc, or much greater

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common neutrino, here, now, is the solar neutrino. The spectrum is:

[image]

so mostly around 300-400 KeV. We don't know the electron neutrino mass, but let's say it's around $m_{\nu}=0.07\,$eV, that puts the Lorentz factor (in the Sun's rest frame, which we are approximately in):

$$ \gamma_{\nu} =\frac E {m_{\nu}} \approx 5,000,000$$

which is squarely in the "ultra-relativistic" category.

In short: the nuclear transitions that produce neutrinos have energies that are much, much, greater than the neutrino mass.

Also: since they are weakly interacting, they don't thermalize with their surroundings, expect perhaps in extreme cases (high density) like core collapse supernovae and the Big Bang.